# Does the RingCentral API support or intend to support tracking fields like those that can be configured via the interface?

Tags: ringcentral

I see there are a number of endpoints both stable and beta in the API documentation for RingCentral Meetings, but I don't see tracking fields mentioned anywhere in the documentation. We would like to be able to associate our customer ID's to the recorded meetings.

[Here's where tracking fields are configured in the RingCentral application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i76gN.png)

[image]